# Using Linq-to-Sql with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created some Linq-to-SQL classes object in VS2008 for SQL Server 2008 R2 fine.

I added a connection to it in server explorer. Then add a stored proc to design surface.

But when I run the app it produces this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)"

I have enabled TCP/IP and Named Pipes for remote connections according to a googled blog.

Comment: are your linq-to-sql classes in a separate classlibrary

Answer (score 1):

Go into your designer file, look in the properties, and find the connection string your designer is using.

Then dig into your dbml file, find the config setting the default constructor of your DataContext is using, and make sure that connection string that setting has is the same as the one from your designer.

Here's where you can find the designer's connection info:

[image]

And this is what my default constructor looks like:

```
    public DataClasses1DataContext() : 
            base(global::Junk.Properties.Settings.Default.ZoomieRestConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

Comment: I can see in the Settings file the correct connection string. Also I am using VS2008.

Comment: Is the connection string in your settings file the same one as in your designer file?  Also, check your config file and make sure you're not overriding the setting in there.

Comment: And you say the designer is working fine, right?  You can drag new tables onto the designer panel?  If so, I would copy paste the text of the connection string in your designer, and pass that string as the connection to your datacontext and see if that works.  DataContext should be generated with a constructor overload that allows you to give it a conn string.  If the string from your designer works like this, then you'll *know* that your setting value isn't what you think it is

Comment: I deleted the Linq2Sql object and recreated but same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the code, its presumably hard to think what going wrong underneath. Anyways here is the code for Linq to SQL connection. Match it with yours

```
SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection();
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = "YourSeverName";
builder.InitialCatalog = "YourDatabase";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
dataConnection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
```